# How to delete application that deploy solution on windows mobile device?

Tags: windows-mobile, visual-studio-2005, activesync

I having problem when I deploy an application on `Windows Mobile Device`.The device that I use is `Symbol Motorola MC75`. The device keep restarting and I have problem to test my application at the device again. I don't know how to solve this, I'm new on Windows Mobile!.  Usually when the application or project tested or deploy at the device, I have to logout from the application first in order to test other application on that device. If I don't doing that the deploy solution will get error on `Visual Studio 2005` telling that another application running on that device or device in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer to this [link](http://www.scantexas.com/asset/resources/download/AppCenter_Windows_Mobile_Administrator_Guide.pdf) to solve the problem and delete the application on the device.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on from the question, but I'm guessing that you have a worker thread started in your application and you've not signalled to stop it before exiting the application.  This was a larger problem in CF 1.0 (since you indicate VS2005, that's a possibility) before the IsBackground property existed for the Thread class.

Comment: after deploy at MC75 device, I have to restart the device to test the application and the problem start at that point... and the device keep restarting......until now. I think maybe the changes I made at the code that responsible the device keep restarting...